# How can I estimate how much memory was used for this quick sort

Tags: c++, quicksort

How can I estimate how much memory was used for this quick sort algorithm. for a quick sort there, in theory, take the deepest of the recursions and multiply by the sum of the sizes of all local variables and so that the resulting memory does not exceed the dimension of the array, I have int arrays of 50k, 100k, 150k, 200k elements.

```
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons,
    long long& extra_comparisons, long long& memory) {
    int pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; ++extra_comparisons, j <= high; j++) {
        if (++comparisons && arr[j] < pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }

    swap(arr[i + 1], arr[high]);

    return i + 1;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high, long long& comparisons,
    long long& extra_comparisons, long long& memory) {
    while (++extra_comparisons && low < high) {
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high, comparisons, extra_comparisons, memory);
        if (++extra_comparisons && pi - low < high - pi) {
            quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1, comparisons, extra_comparisons, memory);
            low = pi + 1;
        }
        else {
            quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high, comparisons, extra_comparisons, memory);
            high = pi - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do this - for a quick sort there, in theory, take the deepest of the recursions and multiply by the sum of the sizes of all local variables and the resulting memory, but I don't have enough skills to implement

Comment: Check in how many places you make copies of data (hint should be none), the rest of memory used is all on stack (arguments times number of recursive calls, n log(n))

Comment: In current C++ I would have expected to see std::span being used instead of "C" style arrays + seperate begin/end offsets. You can't help it most datastructure classes haven't been updated for 30 years, so they don't really teach you C++ as it is currently being used.

Comment: it's quite hard to estimate, it'll partly depend on the compiler and which variables actually end up in memory rather than just being registers, then you'll also need to know which registers the compiler is saving to the stack before recursing. You'd probably be better off just measuring the usage by comparing the stack pointer at the first call to the stack pointer at the deepest recursion

Comment: @PepijnKramer with `std::ranges` at hand, I wouldn't even try to start with old school `for`; I'd just keep it as a hint. It is really frustrating to still see raw pointers all over the globe.